# Emulating Oracle's lag() in mysql

Tags: mysql, lag

I have a simple table with a delivery date and quantity. I'm trying to write a query that will return the current delivery date, the previous date, and quantity. I need both the delivery and previous dates accessible to my where clause.

When I run my statement with mysql or phpMyAdmin, the previous date is NULL for all results. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE delivery
(`delivery_date` int(11), quantity float);

INSERT INTO delivery
(`delivery_date`, `quantity`)
VALUES
    (1399953600, 84),
    (1414382400, 109.4),
    (1418187600, 124.5);
```

My query:

```
SELECT s.quantity AS quantity, s.start_date AS start_date, s.delivery_date AS delivery_date
FROM (SELECT quantity, @start AS start_date, @start := delivery_date AS delivery_date,
            (SELECT @start := NULL) AS vars
      FROM delivery d
      ORDER BY start_date ASC) s
```

I've set up the query I'm working with on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78315/2/0).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simplify your query by putting the variable initialization in the from clause:

```
select quantity
     , @start as start_date
     , @start := d.delivery_date as delivery_date
from (select @start := null) as vars, 
     delivery as d
order by d.delivery_date;
```

I think the problem is that the `@start` variable is initializated to null for every fetched row. By moving the variable definition to the `FROM` clause it will be initialized only once.

Check the updated [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78315/4) and try yourself.

Hope this helps